# AES encryption time difference for same data

Tags: aes, performance

When encrypting same data with AES, encryption time for the first encryption is longer than the second one.  In the same program, I have written `encrypt()` function twice and measure elapsed time. I don't know why?

Comment: If you only ran the test twice the answer is probably due to caching.

Comment: If I ran encryption twice with different message and different key, the same event occurs. How to remove caching?

Comment: The caches involved are likely the cpu data/instruction caches, which you basically cannot do anything about. When timing the performance of software the test needs to be run a large number of times; This will let the cache "heat up" at the beginning and everything afterwards should be more or less consistent in how long it takes. This applies to measuring the execution time of software in general and isn't limited to crypto algorithms.

Comment: Then , how to know the real time comparison of two encryptions?

Comment: Establish how long it takes in the general case via the method I recommended above. Then perform the actual encryption procedures you want to time and measure their differences from the established average. Note this still won't necessarily indicate how long the encryption algorithm itself took, which is why the test has to be run lots of times: the processor does lots of other stuff, and there's countless events that could cause the amount of time taken to fluctuate wildly (cache-miss/reading from swap/not enough cpu time to share/etc).

Comment: By running several time and making average, the encryption time takes only 1 ms.  Is it real encryption time??

Comment: You may be limited by the resolution of the timer you are using to measure. Other then that I can't say.

Comment: related answer http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29175/explain-same-encryption-time-for-two-files-of-different-sizes?rq=1